# "Open PowerShell window here" File Explorer context-menu command breaks with folder names with apostrophes (single quotes)

Tags: windows-explorer, powershell, context-menu

In Windows 10, Shift-right-clicking on a folder or in the background in File Explorer adds an "OpenPowerShell window here" command to the context menu.

However, the command used to open the PowerShell window is ill-defined (as of at least W10 release ID 1709) in that it incorrectly assumes that folder names never contain embedded `'` characters:

```sh
# !! Breaks with folder names such as "a'b"
powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'
```

See below for a fix, but note that it requires administrative privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update: A standalone command --- no script file dependency.

Copy, paste, and execute this code in a **PowerShell** console for an instant "proof-of-concept" demo:

```
$msg = @'
$Args[0] : {0}
$Args[1] : {1}
'@
&{echo ($msg -f $Args[0], $Args[1])} --% I'm an unquoted string with an apostrophe and spaces.
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> $msg = @'
>> $Args[0] : {0}
>> $Args[1] : {1}
>> '@
>> &{echo ($msg -f $Args[0], $Args[1])} --% I'm an unqoted string with an apostroohe and spaces.
$Args[0] : --%
$Args[1] : I'm an unqoted string with an apostroohe and spaces.
PS C:\>
```

- (interesting that `--%` is both functional and captured as an argument)

The "magic bullet" is the [***Stop parsing token***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.4#the-stop-parsing-token): `--%`. Per the documentation:

> The stop-parsing symbol (--%), introduced in PowerShell 3.0, directs
> PowerShell to refrain from interpreting input as PowerShell commands or
> expressions.
> ...
> When it encounters a stop-parsing symbol, PowerShell treats the remaining
> characters in the line as a literal.

Though intended for use with arguments to executables, it also works with arguments to script blocks as the above code demonstrates.

So to execute `Set-Location` with an unquoted path, the syntax is:

```
    &{Set-Location -LiteralPath $Args[1]} --% <unquoted path>
```

And thus our registry command becomes:

```
    powershell.exe -NoExit -Command &{Set-Location -LiteralPath $Args[1]} --%% %V
```

- Note the doubled percent sign (`%%`) is needed to produce the literal `%` symbol in the resulting command.

To modify the command machine-wide, edit the registry directly. The relevant keys are:

- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\Shell\PowerShell\Command`
- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Shell\PowerShell\Command`

1. [Take ownership of the key and assign yourself full control](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-take-ownership-of-registry-keys-and-assign-full-permissions/).
2. Edit the `(Default)` value, changing it to:

   ```
    powershell.exe -NoExit -Command &{Set-Location -LiteralPath $Args[1]} --%% %V
   ```
3. Remove the `Full Control` permission you added for your user.
4. Change owner back to `TrustedInstaller` by speecifying `NT Service\TrustedInstaller` as the username in the steps you followed to take ownership.

To modify the command on a per-user basis, simply create and edit the registry keys:

- `HKCU\Softwar\Classes\Directory\Background\Shell\PowerShell\Command`
- `HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\Shell\PowerShell\Command`
  Changing the value of `(Default)` to:

  ```
   powershell.exe -NoExit -Command &{Set-Location -LiteralPath $Args[1]} --%% %V
  ```

or just copy, pasee, and execute the follwoing:

```
'Background\','' | ForEach{
    $splat = @{
        'Path'    = ('HKCU:\Software\Classes\Directory\{0}Shell\PowerShell\Command' -f $_)
        'Value'   = 'powershell.exe -NoExit -Command &{Set-Location -LiteralPath $Args[1]} --%% %V'
    }
    New-Item @splat -Force
}
```

---

---

### Original Reply

For a 5.1 workaround, I can't think of a way with just a **PowerShell** command line, but calling a one-line script seems to do the trick:

(Code edit/improvement per @mklement0's comment)

```
### OpenHere.ps1
Set-Location -LiteralPath $Args[0]

### (HKCU|HKLM)\Software\Classes\Direcory[\Background]\Shell\PowerShell\Command
###
###powershell.exe -noexit -File "C:\Path\to\OpenHere.ps1" "%V"
###
```

- Save as "OpenHere.ps1" to an appropriate location
- You can then modify either:

  - `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Shell\PowerShell\Command`
    if you have Admin access and are comfortable dealing with ownership and permissions.
    Otherwise, you can create per-user entries under:
  - `HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\Shell\PowerShell\Command`

The syntax for the registry command line is:

- `powershell.exe -noexit -File "C:\Path\to\OpenHere.ps1" "%V"`

---

Here's a "self-installing" version of the above code that will create the context menu entries under `HKCU`(per-user mod).

- Save the following as a `.ps1` file in the directory where it will reside.
- Run the script from a **PowerShell** console with no arguments. The code uses the current Path\FileName of the `.ps1` file in the command line it creates.

```
### OpenHere.ps1
If ($Args) {   ### Launched from context menu
    Set-Location -LiteralPath $Args[0]
} Else     {   ### Create HKCU registry entries
    'Background\','' | ForEach {
        $splat = @{
            'Path'   = ('HKCU:\Software\Classes\Directory\{0}Shell\PowerShell\Command' -f $_)
            'Value'  = ('powershell.exe -NoExit -File "{0}" "%V"' -f $PSCommandPath)
            'Type'   = 'ExpandString'
        }
        New-Item @splat -Force
    }
}

###   The "(Default)" value is created as a REG_EXPAND_SZ to allow for subsequent
###   editing that can include environmental variables
```

Comment: @mklement0:  Thanks. Edited with your suggested improvement. You made me Goggle " whitespace normalization" !!! :D

Comment: :) Nice touch to make the script self-installing.

Comment: On further reflection, I think your answer deserves to be the accepted one. Nice job.

Comment: @mklement0:  Thanks! I couldn't let it go and I figured out a standalone command that doesn't depend on a script file! Will update answer tomorrow (posting this from phone).

Comment: Nicely done; didn't know that `--%` also worked with script blocks (albeit quirkily).

Answer (score 2):

**Preface**

- [Keith Miller's helpful answer](https://superuser.com/a/1822513/139307) is a pragmatic, automated solution - the only thing to note is that it only works at the *user level*.
- The answer below may be of interest for an *all-users* solution and for technical background; the `OpenHere.ps1` from Keith's answer can equally be used in an all-users solution (except for the self-installing part).

---

<sup>Tip of the hat to [LesFerch](https://superuser.com/users/1283806/lesferch) for all his input.</sup>

Note:

- This fix **requires administrative privileges** (running *with elevation*).

Open `regedit.exe` and **apply the following steps to *both* of the following registry keys**: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell\command` and
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell\command`:

- Preparation: **modify the permissions** so that modification of the value (the PowerShell command) becomes possible:

  - **Alternatives to manual permission modification**:

    - @LesFerch mentions the following third-party utilities as *alternatives* to manual permission modification, by allowing you to run `regedit.exe` directly as the `NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller` user:

      > [PowerRun](https://www.sordum.org/9416/powerrun-v1-6-run-with-highest-privileges/) (my preferred), [AdvancedRun](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/advanced_run.html). This is a much safer option than messing with permissions (which people often get wrong and break things).
    - [Keith Miller's helpful answer](https://superuser.com/a/1822513/139307) mentions defining *user-level* keys as an alternative - which doesn't require elevation, but limits the solution to the *current user*.
  - Right-click on the `command` subkey and select `Permissions...`
  - Click on `Advanced` and:

    - make the `Administrators` group the *owner* of the key
    - give the `Administrators` group full control of the key
  - Note: I am not aware of any adverse effects of these modifications, but do tell us if you know of any.
    However, to be safe, you may revert these modifications after modifying the command as described below, which entails restoring the `TrustedInstaller` security principal as the owner of the `command` key; note that you must specify it as
    `NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller`.
- Now replace the `command` key's `(Default)` value with the following (see the note re console settings / colors below):

  ```
  cmd /c set "_dir=%V%" & powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath $env:_dir
  ```

  - Note:

    - By virtue of calling via `cmd`, you'll get the latter's console settings instead of Windows PowerShell's, which notably include a blue background.

      - You can avoid this by placing `start` before `powershell.exe`, which opens a *new window* with the usual settings and colors, but the downside is that the original, transient window that gets invariably created for `cmd.exe` briefly flashes on the screen.
      - [Keith Miller's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1822513/139307) offers an alternative via a *helper `.ps1` script*, which allows direct invocation via `powershell.exe -File` and therefore avoids the flashing problem; the `-File` [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) parameter treats its arguments *literally*, so the problem described below when using `-Command` doesn't apply.

        ```
        powershell.exe -NoExit -File "C:\Path\to\OpenHere.ps1" "%V"
        ```
    - Calling *via `cmd /c`* is the *most robust* and *safe* option:

      - The value of `%V` could only syntactically break the `set` command if it contained `"` characters, which is by definition impossible (file and folder names cannot contain `"`).
      - However, if a folder name contains something that looks like a `cmd.exe` environment-variable reference *verbatim* (e.g. `%OS%`) *and* the referenced variable exists, the reference is expanded, causing changing to that folder to either fail or - hypothetically - a different folder to be targeted.
      - The reason that the command cannot just use `cd` as part of the `cmd.exe` call is that `powershell.exe` malfunctions when called from a folder whose name happens to contain `[` or `]` (e.g. `foo[0]`). This bug has been fixed in the [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) CLI, `pwsh.exe`, so there you could simply use:

        ```
        # PowerShell 7+
        cmd /c cd /d "%V" & pwsh.exe
        ```

        - In fact, `pwsh.exe`'s new [`-WorkingDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh#-workingdirectory---wd---wo) parameter enables *direct* invocation (this is not only more efficient, but also avoid the console-settings problem):<sup>[1]</sup>

          ```
          pwsh.exe -WorkingDirectory "%V\."
          ```
    - While calling `powershell.exe` directly *is* an option, it invariably involves *tradeoffs*:

      - If your folder names may contain literal `'` characters, but NEVER contain literal `` ` `` or `$` characters, you can use `"..."` (an [*expandable* (interpolating) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)) instead, but this comes with the following
        **CAVEAT**:

        - While the command would simply *malfunction* with verbatim folder names such as `` foo`bar `` or  `$foo` (or - hypothetically - target a *different* directory), it could result in *unwanted execution of commands*, via carefully - maliciously - crafted folder names that contain `$(...)` subexpressions.

          ```
          powershell.exe -NoExit -Command "Set-Location -LiteralPath \"%V\""
          ```

It should be possible to script the above steps.

---

<sup>[1] `\.` is appended is so to ensure that *root* paths such as `C:\` are properly handled too; otherwise, the PowerShell CLI would (justifiably) interpret `"C:\"`, for instance, as `C:` followed by an *escaped* `"` character, i.e., in effect as *verbatim* `C:"`, which *breaks*.</sup>